# desktop gadgets obscure icons

Tags: windows-7, icons, desktop-gadget

I'm using Windows 7 with pretty basic configuration. I have a few dekstop gadgets (clock, cpu and network meter, etc) which for some reason obscure the desktop icons. As far as I could understand this is not supposed to happen... yet it does.

Any way to change this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: A screenshot would help because it’s not clear what you mean. Are you saying that desktop icons are supposed to display *over* gadgets?

Comment: Can you expand on "obscures the icons"?  Perhaps provide a picture?  Why not just move the gadgets, or the icons?  What do you expect to have happen?

Comment: The gadgets are displayed over icons... I was expecting them to be organized and do not overlap. I can move them, but when the resolution changes which happens when I connect my laptop to a docking station it all gets messed up again.

Comment: See attached screenshot

Comment: Looks fine to me. The gadgets are not part of the desktop, so the icons won’t move around them. Can you expand on your statement *as far as I could understand this is not supposed to happen*. Where did you get this impression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desktop gadgets float *over* the desktop, the icons are *on* the desktop.

Short of moving your icons, perhaps you can get away with changing the gadgets' opacity by right-clicking them:

[image]